# Can't install the Ubuntu SDK due to broken qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu dependency

Tags: installation, command-line, application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I tried to install the Ubuntu SDK on my Ubuntu 13.10 Virtual machine(VMwarePlayer) by typing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk` in the Terminal. the process gets stuck at a point and is unable to go further so terminates. The final window of the terminal says the following:

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 1,190 kB in 51s (22.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
mrwhite@ubuntu:~$
```

what do I do?

Comment: The SDK team PPA is currently broken, according to a note on the [install page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

First install `aptitude` package by running,

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then install `ubuntu-sdk` through aptitude,

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-sdk
```